# Deploying AKS agent pool managed identity outside of MC_ resource group

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

When rolling out my AKS cluster

```
az deployment group create --template-file template.json --parameters parameters.d.json -g <resource_group>
```

three managed identities are created. These resources are located, by default, in the Managed Cluster resource group (with prefix `MC_`). I would like the `agentpool` managed identity (for vmss) to reside in another resource group.

Ideally I'd like to keep these managed identities when redeploying the cluster, however, the `_MC` resource groups are deleted and created again. Is there an option to deploy these managed identities in another resource group where they have a longer lifetime? Can this be configured in the `template.json`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which managed identities you have because it depends on which add-ons is enabled. Most add-on identities can't be managed outside the cluster, but you can use a user-assigned identity for the kubelet and agentpool (preview) identity. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#summary-of-managed-identities) of the identities for AKS, it tells for which feature you can bring your own identity.

Since it is in preview for the agentpool identity, I'm not sure that this can be done via an ARM tempalte yet. There is an identity field, but I suspect it's for the kubelet identity and not the agentpool. I might be wrong though, you should give it a try.